# Move text and options into a input html and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Im working on a chrome extension where one specifies an Item he wants, the colour, the size, and other certain options; some of there options include a slider and radio buttons and a select option.

He then press the add button and all this information gets inputed into a big box and sort of creates an input with this specfied info just like this example.

[image]
how would I do something like this. here is my html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HP</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="items.css">
<body>

<div class="bg">

    <button id="droplist-btn" class="droplist-btn">Add By Droplist</button> 

    <!-- ADD ARROW IMAGE THAT POINTS TO THE RIGHT AND WHEN CLICKED ROTATES THE IMAGE TO POINT DOWNWARDS -->

    <input type="text" id="item-code-input" class="item-code-input" placeholder=""></input>
    <button type="submit" id="add-item-code" class="add-item-code">+</button>
    <select type="text" id="sizes-item-code" class="sizes-item-code">
        <option value="Small">Small</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="Large">Large</option>
        <option value="XLarge">XLarge</option>
        <option value="One Size">One Size</option>
    </select>
    <input type="radio" id="item-code-radio" class="item-code-radio" name="item-radio" checked="checked" />
    <label for="item-code-radio">Item Code</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" id="keyword-radio" class="keyword-radio" name="item-radio" checked="checked" />
    <label for="keyword-radio">Keyword</label>




    </div>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="items.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

any help would be appreciated Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Controls in jQuery generally use the [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to set their `value`. Certain controls like the `radio button` require the [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method and setting `checked` to `true`.

See the code below for setting the value for inputs and selects

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input#item-code-input").val("06453");
  $("select#sizes-item-code").val("XLarge");
  $("input#item-code-radio").prop("checked", true);
  $("input#keyword-radio").prop("checked", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="item-code-input" class="item-code-input" placeholder=""></input>
<button type="submit" id="add-item-code" class="add-item-code">+</button>
<select type="text" id="sizes-item-code" class="sizes-item-code">
    <option value="Small">Small</option>
    <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="Large">Large</option>
    <option value="XLarge">XLarge</option>
    <option value="One Size">One Size</option>
</select>
<input type="radio" id="item-code-radio" class="item-code-radio" name="item-radio" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" id="keyword-radio" class="keyword-radio" name="item-radio" checked="checked" />
```

Comment: thank you but how would I use this to input it into a table when I press the add//submit button @ZackaryJones

Comment: You want to use jQuerys [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event handler on the submit button. `$("#submitbutton").click(function(){ //on submit button click code});`. I am on my phone so sorry for sytax errors in advance.